# Is Opentaps open source dead?

Tags: opentaps

We have been trying to find information about opentaps recent development but most of the timestaps are years old.

-What is the commit level on this project?

-How many active developers are on this project?

-What is the roadmap of this project?

-Is there any real recent development going on?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a question for the maintainers of a specific project.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that Opentaps is not dead at all. We are working on the version 2 of the project and that's the reason you do not see commits there.

If you need any help of information please let me know.

Comment: Could you give any pointer where to see the source code and follow the development on version 2? Is it still based on OfBiz or copmletely rewritten?